# Getting the Baseline for SWT Label

Tags: swt, label, baseline

I want to get the baseline for a Label in SWT, however I don't know if this is possible at all?

In Swing, there is a method `getBaseline()`. [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ComponentUI.html)

Which returns the baseline. I would need this for SWT as well? Is this possible?

Comment: Could you elaborate why you need the baseline?

Comment: If I have two labels next to each other, I want to know if the baseline of the two labels is the same.

Comment: Which `Layout` do you use?

Comment: Add screen-shot for better understanding

Comment: I want to write a test for the following case: I have to Labels next to each other and now I want to know if the text is on the same horizontal line (baseline)

Comment: Because SWT uses native implementations of the controls it doesn't necessarily know the baseline the control will use. If the labels have the same font and use a layout like `RowLayout` or `GridLayout` they will be aligned.

Comment: However can't it be possible that the label as a top inset? Or image that the second label's height is larger, then the text won't be on the same baseline